# Configure MySQL strict off option in Ubuntu

Tags: database-administration, mysql

I have configured sql_mode option under mysqld in my.cnf located on path /etc/mysql/my.cnf in Ubuntu as follows.

```
nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

my config file looks like :

```
[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
#datadir                = /media/Others/Data/mysql
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
sql_mode        = 'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
```

I have changed sql_mode to make strict off, and restarted mysql service using

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

but when I am running following command in workbench, it shows me nothing to change.

```
select @@GLOBAL.sql_mode
```

result is:

```
NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

Does my config file wrong or located on other place? How do I set option strict off?

Thanks.

Comment: @taro, which variable? can you please give me variable name for the config file?

Comment: i don't see what's the problem. You have set the same thing in config file and getting the same thing. There are no STRICT_ALL_TABLES or STRICT_TRANS_TABLES